# How to cancel a checkbox in a DataGridView from being checked

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, unchecked

I have a datagridview that is databound. How can I cancel the checkbox being checked in the datagridview if some condition is not met?

```
private void dataGridViewStu_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridViewStu.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}

private void dataGridViewStu_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is to handle the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event on `DataGridView`. Check your condition and ensure the current cell is a `CheckBoxCell` then call `CancelEdit` if both conditions are met.

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (youShouldCancelCheck &&
      this.dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty &&
      this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
  {
    this.dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
    // Addition code here.
  }
}
```

**Edit**

I've added an additional condition to the `if` statement to check if the cell is dirty before running the `CancelEdit` and your additional code.  This should no longer run twice.  What was happening was:

1. User clicks checkbox.  `IsCurrentCellDirty = true` and `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` is fired.
2. Conditions are met.  `CancelEdit` is fired, which cancels all changes and sets `IsCurrentCellDirty = false`. Thus `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` is fired again.

`CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` will still be fired twice, but code within the conditional will only be run when dirty.

Comment: I tried your code and it "works" but I need to run extra code right after the CancelEdit method and it seems to run that extra code twice. It should only run it once.

Comment: @Jnr Where are you running the additional code so I can reproduce the error?  I'll take a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Let me edit your code in your answer so you can see what I mean.

Comment: this.dataGridView1.CancelEdit(); work for me and is that i was looking for, caus simply stopping the flux of the program by exit specific function or similar dosn't stop the propagation of the event.