# CheckBox in DataGridView Won't Evaluate if Cell Has Focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

The first column in a DataGridView (dgv1) has checkboxes.  Interestingly, when you click on the last checkbox desired, as soon a you loop through the rows for that column to evaluate checked items, the last cell checked (with a cursor on it) does not evaluate to true.  The syntax for looping through the checkboxes in column 0 is below:

```
    Dim NumCBChecked As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
        If CBool(dgv1(0, i).Value) = True Then
            NumCBChecked += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Is there a way to set the focus to false if the cell containing the last checkbox checked is in edit mode?

BTW, refreshing the edit status (below) did not help before looping:

```
    dgv1.RefreshEdit()
```

Comment: Have you tried  ... `dgv1.EndEdit()` ...  or  ... `dgv1.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)`  ?

Comment: Thanks - dgv1.EndEdit() worked.

Comment: [DataGridView CheckBox selection bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693094/7444103) -- [Programmatically check a DataGridView CheckBox that was just unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031996/7444103) -- [Bound DataGridView not updating to display information + sorting issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006605/7444103)

Comment: Please don't leave questions unanswered. If you worked out the solution based on comments then add your own answer and accept it, so that we can see that you don't need any more help without wasting our time opening your question and reading it, only to find a comment that says it's resolved.

Comment: thx - that's a great suggestion.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

Per @JohnG's comment, the suggestion worked as follows:

```
dgv1.EndEdit()
Dim NumCBChecked As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
    If CBool(dgv1(0, i).Value) = True Then
        NumCBChecked += 1
    End If
Next
```