# How to exclusively set the value of a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a `List<Car>` objects that have a `bool` property named **`Marked`**.
I want to **check / uncheck** the Cell corresponding to this property, in a way that **only one** `Car` can be selected at the **same time**.
I want that the value of this property is updated in the bank.

Sample table:

| Car Name | Marked |
| --- | --- |
| a |  |
| b |  |

The problem is I can't check the state of CheckBox Cells.
This is what I tried, but it's not working:

**Example 1:**

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell dataGridViewCheckBoxCell = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Marked"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

if(Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridViewCheckBoxCell.Value) == true)
{
        //some code
}
else if(Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridViewCheckBoxCell.Value) == false)
{
        //some code
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk =(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["Marked"];

    if (chk.Value == chk.TrueValue)
    {
        chk.Value = chk.FalseValue;
    }
    else
    {
        chk.Value = chk.TrueValue;
    }
}
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Bind your DataGridView to a datatable and attach an event handler to the ColumnChanged event that un-sets the bools in the other rows

Comment: @CaiusJard `ColumnChanged`?

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the `CellContentClick` (or `CellClick`) event of your DataGridView to set the state of a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` that should be a single choice (hence behaving as a RadioButton).

Store the Cell object currently selected when the Cell meets the criteria (its OwningColumn is a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` named `Marked`).
Change the state of this Cell if it's the one currently selected, or reset it back to `false` if it's not.
In this case, set the current Cell to the one just selected and set its state to `true`.

Then you don't need to loop all the Rows each time a CheckBox changes value.

If you need to, call `[DataGridView].EndEdit()` to update the value immediately.

For example:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell currentCheckBoxCell = null;

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    var dgv = sender as DataGridView;

    if (dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell && 
        cell.OwningColumn.Name == "Marked")
    {
        if (currentCheckBoxCell is null) currentCheckBoxCell = cell;
        if (cell == currentCheckBoxCell) {
            cell.Value = !(bool)cell.Value;
        }
        else {
            currentCheckBoxCell.Value = false;
            currentCheckBoxCell = cell;
        }
        // Affects CellValueChanged
        // dgv.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: DataGridCheckBoxCell Single Selection]

See also [DataGridView CheckBox selection bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693094/7444103) to select a CheckBox Cell by clicking anywhere in a Row and while immediately update the data source.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear “where” the first code snippet is called from so I will focus on the second snippet of code.

One of the problems you will have comes from the `if` statement…

```
if (chk.Value == chk.TrueValue) …
```

This condition `chk.Value == chk.TrueValue` may not throw an error, HOWEVER… this is checking two different OBJECTS… `chk.Value` is an OBJECT as is `chk.TrueValue` … so it makes sense that the two “different” OBJECTS would NEVER be equal.

One way to solve this is to simply “cast” those OBJECTS to `bool` values like…

```
if ((bool)chk.Value == (bool)chk.TrueValue) {…
```

HOWEVER the above line of code will ONLY work “IF”… the check box columns `TrueValue` AND `FalseValue` properties have been SET like…

```
CheckBoxColumn.TrueValue = true;
CheckBoxColumn.FalseValue = false;
```

IF you have NOT set the Check box column’s two properties `TrueValue` AND `FalseValue` like above… then the Check box columns `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` will be `null` and this will cause the line of code … `if ((bool)chk.Value == (bool)chk.TrueValue) …` to throw an exception since `chk.TrueValue` is `null` and the cast to a `bool` will throw a `null` exception.

Therefore, if you DO SET the Check box columns `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` then you will have to “cast” the objects to `bool` values in order for the comparison to work as shown above.

Given all this… you may want to re-consider using the Check box columns `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` as the intended purpose of those properties is to allow you to “change” the actual `true` and `false` values to something else that is not necessarily a `true` or `false` value.

It is unimportant how you would use these properties in that context as it appears very clear that in this context… setting the Check box columns `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` properties to `true` and `false` is somewhat superfluous and creates more work for you.

So in this case, I suggest you completely drop using the Check box columns `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` properties.

If you want to ensure that only ONE check box is checked in the column… then you could wire up the grids `CellContentClick` event. If the check box value changed, then simply “uncheck” all the cells in that column.

Fortunately, the grids CellContentClick will fire “before” it actually sets the check box cell, so unchecking them all works out fine for both checked and unchecked states. Crude yes, but it should work.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Marked") {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
      if (!row.IsNewRow) {
        row.Cells["Marked"].Value = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: Also I do not necessarily agree with your comment that… _”So you need to keep a reference to the currently checked cell to exclude it when you uncheck the others.”_ … I may agree with this if there was a lot of data or some other possible reason, however, I intentionally avoided creating a variable that kept track of the checked cell. Fortunately, the grids `CellContentClick` will fire “before” it actually sets the check box cell, so unchecking them all works out fine for both checked and unchecked states. There is no need to keep track of which one is checked.