# How can I select all checkboxes with DataGridView of C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to select all checkboxes, but It have an error.

If I click the full check/release checkbox at the top while a column containing a checkbox is selected, the selected area doesn't change.

How should I solve it?

[image]

The picture above is after clicking the full release.

This is my test code.

The function dataGridView1_CellPainting() and dgvCheckBox_CheckedChanged() are used for full check/release operation.

```
namespace TestWinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> saved_file_names = new List<string>();
        int table_index = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "열기";
            ofd.Filter =  "txt파일 | *.txt";
            ofd.Multiselect = true; //  파일 다중 선택

            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (string file_name in ofd.FileNames)
                {
                    //  1. 중복체크
                    if (saved_file_names.Contains(file_name))
                        continue;

                    //  2. 중복되지않은 파일들을 추가.
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[table_index].Cells[1].Value = table_index + 1;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[table_index].Cells[2].Value = file_name;
                    saved_file_names.Add(file_name);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[table_index].Cells[3].Value = "none";
                    table_index++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool is_checked = false;
            List<int> delete_index = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < table_index; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true)
                    delete_index.Add(i);
            }

            if (delete_index.Count == 0)
                return;

            delete_index.Reverse();

            foreach (var index in delete_index)
            {
                table_index--;
                saved_file_names.RemoveAt(index);
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == -1)
            {
                e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                Point pt = e.CellBounds.Location;

                int nChkBoxWidth = 15;
                int nChkBoxHeight = 15;
                int offsetx = (e.CellBounds.Width - nChkBoxWidth) / 2;
                int offsety = (e.CellBounds.Height - nChkBoxHeight) / 2;

                pt.X += offsetx;
                pt.Y += offsety;

                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                cb.Size = new Size(nChkBoxWidth, nChkBoxHeight);
                cb.Location = pt;
                cb.Checked = true;
                cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(dgvCheckBox_CheckedChanged);

                ((DataGridView)sender).Controls.Add(cb);

                e.Handled = true;

            }

        }

        private void dgvCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                r.Cells[0].Value = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: [DataGridView CheckBox selection bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693094/7444103) -- Read the notes -- You don't need the `OptionsChanged` event invocation, it's specific to that question. Also specific to that question is the *click anywhere* thing. You may want to act when the CheckBoxCell is clicked instead.

Comment: See [Toggling the States of all CheckBoxes Inside a DataGridView Column](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42437/Toggling-the-States-of-all-CheckBoxes-Inside-a-Dat)

Comment: Thank you all, I will refer to what you told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using Data Binding with your `DataGridView` which can simplify what you're trying to do. By defining a `Record` class with your `bool IsChecked` property, the checkbox row is created automatically when you add that record to a binding list *of* those records. Then you can manipulate that check by setting the property in your record instead of making calls on the UI object itself.

Clicking the header cell :

- If All are either checked or unchecked then all will toggle.
- If there is a mix of checked and unchecked, then all will be promoted to checked.

Here's a working sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/data-grid-view-binding-demo.git).

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dgv_ac
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wait for the main form to be created, then attach 
        /// your Binding List as the data source of the DGV
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = this.DataSource;
            initDGV();
        }

        private void initDGV()
        {
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

            // Now you can populate the DataGridView simply
            // by adding some records to the list.
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DataSource.Add(new Record { Number = i, FileName = $"MyFile_{i}.txt" });
            }


            // Once the first record is added, the Columns information is
            // available and we can do column formatting.
            dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.FileName)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            var checkboxColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.IsChecked)];
            checkboxColumn.HeaderText = string.Empty;
            checkboxColumn.Width = 40;
            dataGridView1.CellClick += onCellClick;
            dataGridView1.CellContentClick += onCellContentClick;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Detect check box click and end the edit mode in this case.
        /// </summary>
        private void onCellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                var cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
                if(cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkbox)
                {
                    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Detect header click and set the records accordingly.
        /// </summary>
        private void onCellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.RowIndex == -1)
            {
                switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
                {
                    case nameof(Record.IsChecked):
                        if (DataSource.Any())   // Check to see if there are any records at all.
                        {
                            if(DataSource.Count(record=>record.IsChecked) == DataSource.Count)
                            {
                                // This block says thet're all chacked or all unchecked.
                                if(DataSource.First().IsChecked) // then they all are
                                {
                                    setAll(false);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    setAll(true);
                                }
                            }
                            else setAll(true); // If they're mixed, make them all checked.
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            void setAll(bool value)
            {
                foreach (var record in DataSource)
                {
                    record.IsChecked = value;
                }
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        public BindingList<Record> DataSource = new BindingList<Record>();
    }

    
    // This is the record class that will provide column 
    // information to the DataGridView automatically.
    public class Record
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
}
```