# How can I remove the cell selection from a checkbox column ? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Greetings to the community.

I am trying to modify a checkbox column of a DataGridView in VB.NET. I hope you can help me.

I am looking to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

That is, even if I click or double click on the cell, the checkbox is not selected.

Part of the code where the columns are added to DataGridView (DvgNeumaticos):

```vb
 If BtnVistaPorFacturar.Checked Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To DgvNeumaticos.Columns.Count - 1
                    DgvNeumaticos.Columns(i).Visible = False
                Next

                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("ColChk").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("CodOS").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("Tipo").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("NroOrden").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("NroOrden").DisplayIndex = 0
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("FechaOS").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("F.Cierre").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("Observacion").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("CodNeumatico").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("Externo").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("CodTercero").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("CodProducto").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("Producto").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("Trabajo").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("NroDocRecepcion").Visible = True
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns("FechaRecepcion").Visible = True
```

---

### New Edit:

```
 If BtnVistaPorFacturar.Checked Then
                Dim chkCol As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
                chkCol.Name = "ColChk"
                chkCol.HeaderText = "Chk"
                DgvNeumaticos.Columns.Add(chkCol)

                dt = WFOrdServicioNeumaticos.Instancia.fdu_NEUM_ORDSERV_VerOrdenesPorFacturar(.Cells("IDAgente").Value)

End If
```

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: From this to this on what condition(s)? And do you have any relevant code to see?

Comment: There is no relevant code, it's a simple DataGridView, but I put the part of code where you can see when columns are added to the DataGridView (DvgNeumaticos).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28355530/14171304.

Comment: It didn't help me

Comment: Just so I'm clear.  You're trying to make the checkbox column ReadOnly?

Comment: not really, I need to check the boxes, but when I double click the cell, the checkbox gets checked and that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something obvious, but I am not sure I understand what you are asking. In your question you state that… _” … even if I click or double click on the cell, the checkbox is not selected.”_ … ? … this is indeed odd, however both gifs you show do NOT demonstrate this. In other words, watching both gifs… the clicked on “cells” are clearly “selected.” … ? …

Comment: Granted the check box is not checked in the second gif… but that is the normal behavior of the check box cell. The first gif DOES appear to “check” the check box when clicking “outside” the check box itself, but… that is NOT the normal “default” behavior of the out-of-the-box `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`. So, I question how the code is doing this without some code/help from you.

Comment: Then in a comment you state that… _”I need to check the boxes, but when I double click the cell, the checkbox gets checked and that shouldn't happen.”_ … ? …. I am not sure what you mean here… the out-of-the-box `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` does NOT automatically “check” the check box no matter how many times the “cell” is clicked "outside" the check box itself. And this is shown in the second gif you posted. In my tests… the only way to “check/uncheck” the check box is to click ON the check box itself. Clicking outside the check box “BOX” does not “check” the check box… Yet you claim otherwise.

Comment: Is it possible there is some other code/event you have (that is not shown) that is possibly changing this default behavior? Looking at the second posted gif… the behavior looks normal yet you claim otherwise. The first gif appears to be checking the check box in a NON-Normal-Default way. The posted code you have which appears to simply make some columns visible… should not have anything to do with the check box being checked or un-checked. Again, I am sorry if I am missing something. Are you using the .Net Framework `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`?

Comment: @JohnG Maybe toggling the check state only by code and not by the mouse and keyboard inputs. Just maybe.

Comment: @lsanchezo If that is what you are trying to achieve then as suggested, just set the `ReadOnly` property of the column to `True`.

Comment: @JohnG Good morning, thank you for answering first of all. I think I have rolled up a lot, what basically shows the first gif is that when I click on the cell my checkbox is checked, which should not happen because what I am looking for is that it works like the second gif that even though I click once or several times the checkbox is never checked.

Comment: I'm using VB.NET, Visual Basic with the .NET framework and I'm very new to this, mostly I program with Javascript or Python, but the programming logic helps me to understand some things and I'm not so lost. Regarding how the checkbox column is declared, I just edited the post so you can see how it is declared.

Comment: Well, it appears there is a disagreement as to what happens when the user clicks the check box cell “outside” the check box itself. You claim that the first picture is the normal (default) behavior of the `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` and I disagree. The first picture is NOT the normal behavior and the second picture IS the normal behavior. And you want the behavior of the second picture… so I must be missing something.

Comment: Indeed, the first image is how the DataGridViewCheckBoxCell is normally, the second one (I guess) has an alteration at code level. In case I didn't explain well, and to make it shorter, what I require is that the checkbox is only checked when I click on the checkbox itself and not when I click on the cell as such.

Comment: What version of .Net Framework are you using? I am testing this with .Net version 4.8. What version of VS are you using? I am using VS 2019. I can only guess we are using a different version of something.

Comment: Yes, I'm forced to use VS 2015 and .Net Framework 3.5.